# Software/methods supporting multiple threads to create hotkey/macro for games

Tags: windows, game, game-development, macros

I want to fix the controls of various games I play. To do so I require an external Windows program/software that is able to:

1. rebind a key to another key
2. check the state of the key(pressed/released)
3. support multiple threads: or a method so 3hotkeys each with their own loops/timers function
4. extra: able to create hotkeys using the shift/ctrl/capslock keys directly

As an example for what I would want for a specific hotkey:

> Basically I need to turn a normal button ingame such as a crouch button into a key setup like a casting skill...it has an initial tap ability...a double tap ability...a cooldown until next time it can send anything...and a way to automate itself so it loops as soon as its ready again, etc.

Not sure if macro or hotkey is the better word for this. Something like autohotkey has most of these things, and will function for individual hotkeys. But it lacks reliability and more importantly doesn't support more than 1 timer across more than 1 hotkey in tandem...the multithread 'mimicking' fails miserably in games regardless of workaround. Something like project autohotkey_H is dead and doesn't have sufficient documentation or support to be utilized. AutoIT functions as a lesser autohotkey.

If the answer is simply a programming language, I don't know how that translates to simulating hotkeys for games so outline that a bit if you can. If the answer is to make the games and your own controls, that's not what I am asking and I can do that fine already thanks.